# SMB3 mounted on linux / Debian - qemu-img Failed to get "resize" lock

Tags: linux, windows, debian, smbclient

I have a Windows 2016 SMB share mounted on a Debian 10 box.  I am using qemu-img to convert an image file the target of which I wish to store on the SMB mount.  When I run the command I get this error:

error while converting qcow2: Failed to get "resize" lock

This suggests that either qemu-img is misinterpreting the lock on the mount or that there is something incorrect with the mount itself.  I note that qemu-img does not seem to support stdout, which is extremely frustrating!

Are there any tunables I can use to bypass this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading / re-negotiating to SMB 2.xx dialect. There are some issues with 3.xx still.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3

Comment: Great idea, according to the article it is not possible to disable only SMB3 (2 and 3 get disabled together), I have tried doing the renegotiation from the linux side using ver=2.1 on the mount but makes no difference.  From what I can see in the docs that specifies a minimum protocol version rather than mandating a specific one.  One option would be to force SMB1, might try that next.

Comment: So event with SMB1 same error occurs